# Google dev console, need to keep redefining variables

Tags: javascript, console

I am testing some javascript with the dev console in google but I am having some problems. Every piece of code I write I can only run once because I get an error saying an identifier has already been declared. I am trying to get my code to work but it is becoming very difficult since I have to go back and change the variable/constants name every single time. Is there a way around this? or something I can do to turn this off? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (Depending on if you're calling things directly from the window object), you can simply wrap the code within a capture/function to contain the state/variables within the function.

This is what most userscripts/anonymous scripts do to prevent global pollution (Creating global variables that would effect the DOM). Any changes you make here (ie. `var test = 'bleh'`) will be set within the function and wouldn't touch any global properties on the window object.

```
(function() {
    //Your code here
})()
```